# How to force boehm gc collect all, right before a program exit

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

I'm learning boehm gc c++ interface now. Not working with it, just curious about. And I follow the official example, writing my classes what could be GCed, in destructor, there is a output, so I can tell whether an instance is GCed or not.
But only if I use a loop to create instances as many as something like a thousand or more could ever trigger a gc collection. If the code is simple like this:

```
class test_gc : public gc
{
public:
    ~test_gc()
    {
        cout << "~test_gc()" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    GC_INIT();
    ::new (GC) test_gc();
    GC_gcollect();
    return 0;
}
```

it seems like the destructor is never called. There is no "~test_gc()" outputed. Also the optimization of the compiler is turned off.
I did some google, find nearly nothing but the official example.

Please help me how to force a gc collection before a program exit, or tell me how to use it in a correct way if I use it wrong.
Many thanks.

Comment: The case I could find some so called "output" was made by gc_cleanup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did some google, find nearly nothing but the official example.

This `Dr.Dobb's` article on [The Boehm Collector for C and C++](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-boehm-collector-for-c-and-c/184401632) has some great examples.

> it seems like the destructor is never called.

To quote the article:

> but if you want the destructor to be called, you must delete the object yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see, so the gc only deal with the memory, not the data holds on it, and not even a destructor. Also gc can't guarantee the order of the collection of each instance.

Answer (score 0):

From the article @Shafik's linked to:

> If you need a new class with destructors that the Boehm collector calls automatically, you may subclass the Boehm collector's class gc_cleanup. It's like class gc except that it arranges for the Boehm collector to call the destructor immediately before recycling an instance's memory. Remember that you have no guarantee that all instances will be recycled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Boehm's collector is conservative -- it doesn't know what values are live pointers and what values are not, so it scans everything that might be live and treats it as if it was.  In your case, since you just called `new` immediately before `GC_collect`, its likely there's a pointer to the object in a register or on the stack somewhere that is making the collector think that it is still alive.  Try putting the `new` in some other function called from `main`, so its frame will be popped before calling `GC_collect`:

```
int func()
{
   ::new (GC) test_gc();
   return 0; /* overwrite the return value register so it doesn't contain the return value from ::new */
}
int main()
{
    GC_INIT();
    func();
    GC_gcollect();
    return 0;
}
```

This makes it more likely there won't be stray pointers to the object stored somewhere, but there are no guarentees.